# Trumbowyg: Django server can detect file upload but not image URL input

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, trumbowyg

I'm using [Trumbowyg](https://github.com/Alex-D/Trumbowyg), a WYSIWYG JavaScript editor which has a feature of rendering images from URLs pasted in. It also has an [upload plugin](https://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/documentation/plugins/#plugin-upload) which enables uploading local images and custom server side handling.

My python/django function `upload_image()` can successfully detect the uploaded image - however when I use the URL image input, my python function cannot detect it. Trumbowyg simply renders the image without going through my python backend.

Here's my code:

```javascript
$('#id_content').trumbowyg({
    btnsDef: {
        // Create a new dropdown
        image: {
            dropdown: ['insertImage', 'upload'],
            ico: 'insertImage'
        }
    },
    // Redefine the button pane
    btns: [
        ['strong', 'em', 'del'],
        ['link'],
        ['image'], // Our fresh created dropdown
    ],
    plugins: {
        // Add imagur parameters to upload plugin for demo purposes
        upload: {
            serverPath: '/upload_image/',
            fileFieldName: 'content_image',
            urlPropertyName: 'url'
        }
    }
});
```

```python
def upload_image(request):
    print('Success') #only prints when I use the upload input, not the URL input
```

Why can in detect the uploaded image but not the URL input?

Comment: Kindly post your urls.py as well...

Comment: Added. I use `upload_image()` in other places and it works fine, (by using `url: '/upload_image/',` in my ajax calls.

Comment: "Why can in detect the uploaded image but not the URL input?" Because that javascript framework doesn't support that and you need to do your own hooks

Comment: Ah ok. Any suggestions how I can go about that? The insert URL function is here I believe: https://github.com/Alex-D/Trumbowyg/blob/develop/src/trumbowyg.js#L1305

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already pointed, Trumbowyg doesn't send the URL to backend if the user uploads the image using a URL.

But if you really want to host the images on your own server, there's a way you can do that.

When the user submits the form, you'll receive the content of the textarea in your backend. You can then read the content and look for `<img src="...">` tag.

At that point, you can check if the `src` value doesn't start with your S3 bucket hostname, you can download that image using [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html) or [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library, save it to your bucket and replace the `src` value.

Since the submitted data will be in HTML format, check out the excellent [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). It will make parsing HTML easy.